# Importing from multiple text files in Solr

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I have two text files, call them A.txt and B.txt. Both A.txt and B.txt have 3 fields. But the semantics are different. Let's name these fields as follows:

```
A.txt : f1, f2, f3
B.txt : f1, f2, f4
```

A.txt and B.txt have same values for f1 and f2, but have a different third field.

I would like to import these files into Solr (I'm using Solr 4.5). But the caveat is that corresponding entries from A.txt and B.txt should have to combined into one single document. So for example, if we have:

```
A.txt
1,50,foo
51,100,bar

B.txt
1,50,xkcd
51,100,qc
```

After dataimport has happened, there should be 2 documents in Solr:

```
1,50,foo,xkcd
51,100,bar,qc
```

If the documents were stored in SQL databases, it would be a simple join query. But since the docs are stored as lines in a CSV file, and I am using LineEntityProcessor with a transformer function to do the dataimport, is there a way of accomplishing this task?

Comment: There is no Solr 5. Do you mean Solr 4.5? Also, what's your primary key? If you did a join, which field/fields would you do it on?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant Solr 4.5. My primary key is f1. If I did a join I would join on f1 and f2.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to import these files into Solr (I'm using Solr 4.5). But the caveat is that corresponding entries from A.txt and B.txt should have to combined into one single document...After dataimport has happened, there should be 2 documents in Solr

This won't work as you intend. By default, Solr treats a document update as the functional equivalent of a transactional delete and insert.

With Solr 4, [atomic update](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates) capabilities permitted some fields to be updated without impacting the rest of the document field data. There are limitations in how those work, as it requires metadata about the update and necessitates XML or JSON formats. The text file structures you've identified won't work with this, though.

My suggestion: save yourself the headache and write a file merge script that combines your text files to produce the record you want prior to storing it in Solr.

Comment: Thanks jro. The only problem in my use case is the fact that new fields may be added to the docs with time. If I do a file merge, then for adding a new field, I'd have to do a complete data import every time a new field is added. How would you go about doing things in this case?

Comment: Would you know if a record is an update as opposed to a new one? If yes, you can use atomic update update format and Solr will merge it for you. But you have to store - not just index - the field for this to happen. You will also need a unique key (you said you need two fields for merge, which could be a problem).